# Why is there an Attribute Error: 'str' object has no attribute 'copy' for this code?

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary, deep-copy

Trying to create a deep copy of a dictionary without using copy module.

```
def deepcopy(data: dict):
    copy_dict = {}

    for keys, values in data.items():
        new_value = values.copy()
        copy_dict[keys] = new_value

    return copy_dict


old = {"Lion": "brave", "Tiger": "striped"}
copied_dict = deepcopy(old)
print(copied_dict)
```

This is the error I get:

```
line 11, in deepcopy
    new_value = values.copy()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'copy'
```

I should be able to create a copy of 'values' but I get this error message instead.

Comment: Your values are "brave" and "striped" neither of which are lists

Comment: Looks like you forgot to post the function header.

Answer (score 1):

No, both `keys` and `values` will be strings. The loop body gets executed once per key/value pair with the variables set to whichever pair it’s on, not to all of them at once.